# Background Image to appear on Hover

Tags: html, css

I have a button that, when hovered over, I would like the background image to display also. (It is an arrow an explanation of the button). There are quite a few questions similar, but I couldn't quite tweak the answers to work for me.

The HTML looks like

```
<div id="header_feedback">
    <a href="#contactForm">
        <img title="Add an Event" src="./img/header_feedback.png" alt="Give us your Feedback"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

the CSS then is

```
#header_feedback
{margin-left:730px;
margin-top:-135px;
position:absolute;}

#header_feedback:hover
{
background: url ('./img/addevent_tip.png');
}
```

Any ideas hugely welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is not with your CSS. [Itagi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636964/259014) correctly identified the minor issue that you can't have a space between `url` and the parens/address.

But there are two other bigger issues:

1. **Invalid image url**: when applied, `background: url('./img/addevent_tip.png');` fails to find a valid image. To fix this, you either need two periods or zero. So either `background: url('/img/addevent_tip.png');` or `background: url('../img/addevent_tip.png');`
2. **Backgrounds applied to opaque images aren't visible**: Since the entire content of the div is an image and that image has no transparency, you will not be able to see the on-hover change even when it happens correctly. You can adjust for this by making part of the image transparent (and, perhaps, setting a background for the non-hover state that leads it to look the way it normally does), or by abandoning the image in favor of CSS spriting.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. About time I learned some sprite usage anyway! Is there any way to make the background fade up and down? I tried transition, but it was moving in from the left instead of staying still.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change it the following way:

```
#header_feedback:hover
{
background: url('./img/addevent_tip.png');
}
```

no whitespace between 'url' and the actual url

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't do the trick, although I imagine it is me doing something small and silly wrong. You can see it not working at debatecalendar.com, with your updates.

Comment: I'm getting: GET http://debatecalendar.com/css/img/addevent_tip.png 404 (Not Found) the relative path is incorrect... try doing '../img/addevent_tip.png' or '/img/addevent_tip.png'

Comment: ok, after further looking into it, that was one thing, the second thing is the layout itself, which is set up wrong (with un-needed large margins which causes the background image to not be displayed because in order to see the background image, it must fit inside the element size

Comment: Thanks for your time Itai. I have changed to using CSS sprites as per one of the other answers. You can see it live. Just as regards that, is there a way to fade in the change in CSS3. I tried transition but it moved the item in as opposed to just fading it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header_feedback a img{ display:none;}
#header_feedback a:hover img{display:block}
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I still need the original image to display, but when hovered over, I'd like to also display the background img